# Conditional Formatting for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Forgive me if this too simple of a question but I have spent alot of time attempting to find the correct formula.  Currently, the data in column C collects the last 4 data totals from column B regardless of years.  I want the data in column D to collect data only if the year in column A is identical.  I have figured out how to do it by creating a column for each year but that makes the excel document exceptionally large and slow and hard to analyze (this is a much smaller sample of the actual excel document).  Thanks so much for any help, I truly appreciate it.  I am using excel 2013.

```
Year    Total   Last 4  Last 4 YTD

2015    5       22  
2015    4       22  
2015    9       18  
2015    3       28  
2015    6       26  
2015    4       29  
2014    5       32  
2014    13      28  
2014    4       32  
2014    7       35  
2013    8       39  
2013    9       36  
2012    8       28  
2012    10      18  
2012    12      6   
2012    6       0
```

Comment: Year, Total Last 4 Years, Total Last 4 YTD? I see three columns of data, no column D. Could you make your data more presentable? And Last 4 YTD, what does that mean exacly? Last 4 or Only last for years including this year now? 5 + 4 + 9 + 3 = 21 = confused.

Comment: I'm sorry when I posted it formatted like that.  It looked more clear when I first typed it out.  2015 is cell A2, 5 is cell B2 and 22 is cell C2.  Column is D is blank.  I'm not sure why it reformatted the post like that.  In column C, the formula is =SUM(B3:B6) which generates the 22.  Column D is blank at the moment under Last 4 YTD.  I imagine I need to use some version of =SUMIF in column D but not sure how exactly to do that for multiple years.  I even have been reading the "Excel 2013 Bible" and can't figure it out.  Thanks again!

Comment: I see. So you want col-4, D2 to be 22, but D3 to be 22, but D4 to be 13 because there are only 3 values in the same year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track: **sumif (** *range*, *criteria*, *sum-range* **)**

[image]

**Range**: last four; prior

**Criteria**: Range A3, matches values in col(A) in Range

**Sum-Range**: Same range, but one column adjacent.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That was exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: @george84 Glad I could help out. If you would just accept the solution by clicking on the check-mark so that the readers know already it's solved. Cheers!